# Why doesn't -fsanitize=undefined pick up on (what I think is) UB?

Tags: c++, g++, undefined-behavior, sanitizer

```cpp
auto vec = std::vector<int>({1, 2, 3});
std::cout << *vec.end() << std::endl;
```

Here is some simple code that I believe to be UB. However, compiling this with the following steps:

```cpp
g++ -std=c++23 -Wall -Wextra -g -fsanitize=undefined -o ./target/src/main.cpp.o src/main.cpp
g++ -fsanitize=undefined -o ./target/main ./target/src/main.cpp.o
```

Results in a perfectly happy sanitizer and an output of `0`!

I thought that the way contiguous collection iterators worked in C++ was that they pointed to the first out-of-bounds memory location.

```
{1, 2, 3} ?, ?, ?, ...
 ^ begin  ^ end
```

My thinking is that the creation of any arbitrary pointer is technically safe, but the dereferencing of this pointer is what is unsafe, so this is a fine method of creating iterators. Of course, this is very unlikely to be something wrong with `fsanitize` so let me know where I'm going wrong! :)

Comment: Yes this is UB.  if the compiler could detect all cases of UB then we would have a lot less problems but it is not an easy task.  Most likely the sanitizer just doesn't catch this.

Comment: That particular case is caught by Asan, not Ubsan. Use `-fsanitize=address,undefined`

Comment: `-fsanitize=address`: https://godbolt.org/z/85zvTneYP

Comment: Ubsan doesn´t catch all cases of UB. In particular don't count on it when looking for violations of library-defined rules, like this "no dereferencing of end iterators" rule.

Comment: There's also `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` which directly enables the container bounds checking, without having to rely on sanitizers figuring it out.

Comment: To expand on n.m.s comment, consider some odd implementation that stores a sentinel end element where `vec.end()` points to. Unlikely but not impossible (could be even useful in a debug build). There would be no way to detect the UB on the lower level, but technically it would still be UB.

Comment: Asan only catches it because it hits a lucky spot. No luck in general case [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/558zPaGK7). So don't count on Asan either.

Comment: all sanitizers are caching some kind of Undefined behaviors. Undefined behavior sanitizer catches some specific group of them: like integer overflow. Address sanitizer catches memory related issues. Thread sanitizer - race conditions, deadlocks. Note also that all sanitizers do not give you any kind of warranty - they have some limitations too and can have false positive and false negative results. Check documentation what can be detected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right; this is undefined behavior, and *some* sanitizer should pick up on it. Clang's UBSan detects it, and GCC's ASan does:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    auto vec = std::vector<int>({1, 2, 3});
    std::cout << *vec.end() << std::endl;
}
```

This produces the error:

```
==1==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x50200000001c at pc 0x00000040153e bp 0x7ffcd56c77c0 sp 0x7ffcd56c77b8
READ of size 4 at 0x50200000001c thread T0
    #0 0x40153d in main /app/example.cpp:6
    #1 0x7faa3ef48082 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082) (BuildId: 1878e6b475720c7c51969e69ab2d276fae6d1dee)
    #2 0x40120d in _start (/app/output.s+0x40120d) (BuildId: b859bb13bb93e5af8f52cb0ac4198ad4bf2002c3)
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Kd9r8EsPe)*

In general, you should typically use `-fsanitize=address,undefined` to catch a wider range of errors. Alternatively, use external tools like [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/).

Comment: if you make the example a little less trivial it still fails to detect: https://godbolt.org/z/TaGKcdM9W

Comment: @NathanOliver I think this might be beyond the power of sanitizers, and could only be picked up by additional runtime assertions. When you add `vec.shrink_to_fit()`, after `vec.clear()`, it picks up on it again.

Comment: To catch library undefined behavior in libstdc++ that doesn't happen to be core language undefined behavior with the concrete implementation, one can use `-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS` and `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`.